# Put Text on MapView

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am trying to put a text on the MapView and can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried the following:

```
yardsToPoint.draw(at: CGPoint(x:50, y:50))
```

This however doesn't work.

Comment: Is using UILabel should solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as @AhmadF suggested is to use a UILabel.

Change the text of the label, move it's location based on a CGPoint, and make it no hidden.